# Is RUP an Agile method

Tags: agile, rup

I have been reading software development methodologies. I came across a line which says that agile methods include Rational Unified Process, Scrum, Crystal Clear, Extreme Programming, Adaptive Software Development, Feature Driven Development, and Dynamic Systems Development Method (DSDM). What I wonder is whether RUP should be in the list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about methodology, not programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rational Unified Process is an Iterative and Incremental process, though by default the average cycle time to deliver working software is still quite long. I personally count RUP as borderline agile, close to long-iterative or short-water-fall.

Its more recent brother, [OpenUp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenUP), is supposedly a more agile version, concentrating on the core aspects of RUP and doing away with many of the less desirable parts.

If you're looking to be "very agile", the Unified Process is probably not going to give you the most flexibility in the end.

Comment: Jesse, any comment on the fact that RUP is somewhat oriented towards  (or maybe oriented around) UML models?

Comment: It's a Rational method, of course they mention a lot of UML models. They're not required though, they're part of the extended principles. Many people never really looked at the Process Customization tools that came with the product. Rational actually allow(s/ed?) you to generate the guidance with only the elements you really needed. You could undress it to be OpenUP to a certain extent.

Comment: Literally from the OpenUP guidance: The more abstract representation could use various representation options. UML could be used either strictly or informally; it is a preferred notation based on its rich semantics and broad usage in the industry. Other techniques could be used to communicate the design. Or the design could use a mix of techniques as applicable. http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/practice.tech.evolutionary_design.base/workproducts/design_D677D182.html?nodeId=32692c99